# how to lazy-load express routes

Tags: node.js, express

I have too many routes in my express app, all of them are loaded when the app started.

I want to load each route only when needed.
so, I tried this approach but with no luck.

```
let app = Router();

app.get('/collections', getRoute('collections'));
// other routes....

function getRoute(route: string): any {
  let [path, func = 'default'] = route.split(':');

  console.log(`getting route: ${path}`);
  return require(`./${path}`)[func];
}
```

collections.ts

```
export default (req,res)=>res.json({ok:1})
```

when the app starts it logs 'getting route: collections' once and in advance (even if it not accessed).

but I want to load this route only when we access the route 'api/collections'